# How to change ID3 tags using VLC via a script?

Tags: vlc-media-player, mp3, id3

I have a number of mp3 files that require to have their ID3 tags to be changed (my car only orders songs by alphabetical order of the title, so I need to prepend the track number to their names). I tried eyeD3 and id3tool and both don't like titles that contain non-English characters or sometimes just fail at random even in songs with only English characters. VLC never failed to edit the tags whatever is the language in the title, but edit all the titles by hand is a tedious work. Is there a way to automate this?